# Is there a wchar_t version of getcwd?

Tags: c++, gcc, wchar-t, getcwd

I am trying to this:

```
wchar_t buff[PATH_MAX];
wgetcwd( buff, PATH_MAX);
```

I have also tried _wgetcwd. Google suggests _wgetcwd is in dir.h, but i have never heard of such a header file.

I'm using GCC 4.3.

Thank you.

Comment: I would check `direct.h` or `wchar.h`.

Comment: What OS? (If the answer to this question is not Windows, then the answer to your question is "there is no such function, forget you ever heard of wchar_t and embrace UTF-8".)

Comment: it's linux. I am not a linux developer. I was looking for wchar_t like it is windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a Unix/Linux system there is no point in looking for a wchar_t version of getcwd. That is because all file names and directory names are just bytes with the exception of the '/' and '\0' characters. You can use UTF-8 encoding with them but the filesystem itself does not care.